# iText Acroform issue

Tags: java, itext

I have created a pdf with iText in A4 landscape using
    `Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());`

Now I want to insert acroforms in the pdf. For that I have created another class and inserted the acroform.

The problem is when I enter text in acroform it is coming vertically instead of horizontally.

This is my code for creating a PDF

```
public void createPDF1(Insured ins) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\xx.pdf"));

    ...
```

Method to insert acroform to existing pdf

```
    protected void manipulatePdf() throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new 
    PdfWriter(DEST));

    PdfFormField personal = PdfFormField.createEmptyField(pdfDoc);
    personal.setFieldName("personal");

    PdfTextFormField name =
    PdfFormField.createText(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(60, 38, 16, 150), "Name", "");
    personal.addKid(name);
    name.setAlternativeName("Name");

    PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).addField(personal, pdfDoc.getFirstPage());

    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Comment: I was able to rotate the name form field itself using `name.setRotation(90);` which resolved the issue. 
But we need to do this for all the form fields.

Comment: Consider using `new Rectangle(842, 595)` instead of `PageSize.A4.rotate()`. This requires no rotation and should prevent your issue.